# How to crawl files with special characters (more than 1) as delimiter, for aws glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, grok, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have this kind of data:-

```
ColumnA~|~ColumnB~|~ColumnC  
xyz~|~1090~|~yes  
abc~|~1011~|~yes
```

How to parse it through glue correctly without the delimiter `~|~`

Tried using grok, but it was unable to parse